# Android Emulator Image Downloading Fails

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to install new Emulator images using Android Studio's SDK Manager but it fails because of my internet problems and it re-starts downloading from the start.

1) Is there any setting for resuming downloads in Android Studio? I checked but found nothing. Please educate me if there is one.
2) If Android Studio doesn't support resuming of SDK downloads, what option do I have? Is there any other way to download system images directly and install them offline?

I've got a very slow internet broadband speed of 512 kbps which is not consistent. It breaks often. I don't have any other option to switch ISP because there is only one in this city.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If downloading resuming is not working for you in the Android Studio SDK Manager, a directory of all the available emulator system images are here in these XML files (found in the Android SDK Manager settings in Android Studio):

Google Play versions of the Android Emulator System Images
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img2-1.xml

AOSP versions of the Android Emulator System Images
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-1.xml

For example to download, the emulator system images for Android O, you can paste this URL directly into Chrome: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/x86-O_r03.zip

Once you download the zip, you will need to put the files in the right SDK location for Android Studio to work correctly. See the screen shot for the location.

[image: Location of Emulator System Images]

Comment: Thanks @Jamal Eason! Yes, I did exactly that and I was able to install the Android O image on my system.
BTW, getting an answer directly from the Android Studio Product Manager just made my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there's a way you can directly download from Google Chrome and install it offline. Now the official Android O system image has been released. You can download and use it in your emulator.

The link is https://developer.android.com/preview/download.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

For those like me who didn't necessarily have a bad Internet connection but struggled with this problem for a while:

I had to update Android Studio to the latest version by switching to the Beta channel, restarted the IDE and tried the installation of the system image again, and it worked. More details on this [AS blog post](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/google-play-system-images-android.html) (the post title is about AS v2.3.2 and Emulator 26.0.2 but you never know, it might work for your combination as it did for my AS v3.1.1 and emulator v27)